# How to resolve digits root?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

well am getting stuck with the challenge, need some explications. Thank you in Adavnce.
Well, i need to make sum of numbers into an array, exp :

1. `16  -->  1 + 6 = 7`
2. `942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15`
3. `15  -->  1 + 5 = 6`

....etc

my code work for sum of just 2 numbers.

```
function digital_root(n) {
    const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(n), Number);

    let sum = arrayOfDigits.reduce(function (memo, val) {
        return memo + val;
    });

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try for a recursive call with the base condition of when number of digit is only one

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return n
  } else {
    const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(n), Number)

    let sum = arrayOfDigits.reduce(function(memo, val) {
      return memo + val
    })

    return digital_root(sum)
  }
}

console.log(digital_root(16))
console.log(digital_root(942))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function digital_root(n) {
const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(n), Number);

let sum = arrayOfDigits.reduce(function(memo, val){

return memo + val;
});
if(sum<10)
return sum;
else
return digital_root(sum);

 }
```